# Attempting to retrieve a variable to check whether form is valid or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to retrieve a variable from my JavaScript form to determine whether or not the form has been validated before.

So, this will be checked when the user clicks the 'Submit' button. I have it set already so it can run a function when this button is clicked.

Validation Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var minChars = 5;
        var characters_error = 'Not enough characters';
        $('#email_status').text("Checking..");  
        if (email != '') {
            if($('#email').val().length <= minChars)
            {
                //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text
                $('#email_status').text(characters_error);
            }
            else if ($('#email').val().length > minChars)
            {
                $.post('validation/refer_validation.php', {email: email}, function(data){
                    $('#email_status').text(data);
                }); 
            } else
            {
                $('#email_status').text('');
            }
         }
    });
});
```

Button Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        if (validated != true)
        {
            // Tell the user that there is an error in the form.
        }
    });
});
```

Notice how I added that Variable called 'validated', that should be set somewhere but this is where I am confused. How would I update the variable and return it to the button? Because the validation code is included in the HTML form but if I created a variable it would probably always Update itself to default because the function is called on key up.

Hopefully this all makes sense.

Comment: since you're using jquery already, why not go for a validation plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling the validation function using the submit button, call it in the onsubmit of the form.  If you return true it will continue and submit the form, if you return false it will cancel the form submission.

```
<form  onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Onsubmit is called just before a submission actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable i.e. outside all the functions, set

```
var validated = false;
```

then set validated accordingly, and it should be read in the submit.

Answer (score 0):

use variable **validate** as global variable,
for every successfull validation make **validate to true**

then it works fine when you click on submit button

Answer (score 0):

Rather than throwing an outer variable around, better might be to log the fact that the form has been validated as a data attribute on the form itself.

Also, validating on click to the button ignores the fact that the form may be submitted via the enter key, so validate on the form's submit event instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('#some_form').on('submit', function() {

        //validated before? forget it
        if ($(this).data('validated')) { alert('already validated'); return false; }

        //else, if first time, log that we're doing it
        $(this).data('validated', 'true');

        //do validation...
   });
});
```